# Android's app an notification's sound is off by default

Tags: android, ionic-framework, push-notification

I have build an app with Ionic and when the users install the apps, by default the sound on notifications is set to off.

Is there a way to set it to on by default ?

I have searched on Google but every time I only find how to set it to on manually or methods to set custom sound.

The code I use to send the notification :

```
device.send_message(messaging.Message(notification=messaging.Notification(title=title, body=body),
            android=messaging.AndroidConfig( notification=messaging.AndroidNotification( sound='default' ), ), 
            apns=messaging.APNSConfig( payload=messaging.APNSPayload( aps=messaging.Aps( sound='default' ), ), )))
```

Comment: i want a answer too

Comment: I found nothing :(